# How to convert to SWR

Tags: typescript, next.js13, swr

I want to use SWR library to call API but not sure why this stuff doesn't work for me.

My code is as follows and it works, however I need to make that call on client side so either need to change that to hook or preferably use SWR. Please help.

```
export async function getSamplingPoints() {
  const client = apiClient();
  const samplingPoint = await client
    .path("/api/SamplingPoint")
    .method("get")
    .create();
  const { data } = await samplingPoint({});
  return data;
}
```

I have tried that:

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { apiClient } from "../apiClient";

export const fetchSamplingPoints = async () => {
  const client = apiClient();
  const samplingPoint = await client
    .path("/api/SamplingPoint")
    .method("get")
    .create();
  const { data } = await samplingPoint({});
  return data;
};

export const useSamplingPoints = () => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR("/api/SamplingPoint", fetchSamplingPoints);

  return {
    data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
  };
};
```

and in component then :

```
const { dataq, isLoading, isError } = useSamplingPoints();
```

but getting undefiend.

Comment: Do you see the request is made in the console? And still undefined data after that? You are also destructuring `dataq` key which is probably a typo.